# Cruisecontrol status for flex project

Tags: apache-flex, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol

I setup Cruisecontrol to auto build a flex project every 1 hour using FlexAnt. The build itself works great - I can see when the project build fails/succeeds in the console perfectly well. But the cruisecontrol dashboard is not updated for the flex project.

I have the sample connectfour project, and when it fails, I can see the red box for the project in the dashboard. This does not happen for my flex projects.

Any ideas on how I can rectify this?

Regards,
Ravi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has not been encountered later. Sorry about that.